# Minimizing average cost when inviting resources over time

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm providing services that I need to find a professional to handle. This happens by inviting multiple professionals and letting them answer yes or no to whether they are available. Each professional has a different cost.

Instead of inviting all the professionals at the same time, I want to invite the cheapest first, then the next cheapest and so on. This gives the cheaper professional more time to answer yes, thus on average giving me a lower cost.

I have a given time period from the invitation of the cheapest professional to a later time when the invitation to the most expensive professional must be sent.

What are the optimal time gaps between inviting resources in that time period which on average yields the minimum cost?

Comment: Is there a cost to simply inviting them? Are you obliged to take in a person if you invite him and he says Yes?

Comment: @Deep Inviting is free. The first one to say yes is taken.